# Confusion about single responsibility in OOP

Tags: oop, solid-principles, single-responsibility-principle

Let's consider the following example:

```
class User
{

}

class FirstUseNotification
{
    function show(User user)
    {
        // check if it was already shown, return if so
        // show a notification
        // mark it as shown in the db or whatever
    }
}

class SomeController
{
    function someMethod()
    {
        firstUseNotification->show(user);
    }
}
```

The show() method seems to break single responsibility by doing 3 things. So i figure this could be rewritten as such:

```
class User
{

}

class FirstUseNotification
{
    function show(User user)
    {
        // show a notification
    }

    function shouldShow(User user)
    {
        // return true if not yet shown
    }

    function markAsShown(User user)
    {
        // flag notification as shown
    }
}

class SomeController
{
    function someMethod()
    {
        if (firstUseNotification->shouldShow(user)) 
        {
            firstUseNotification->show(user);
            firstUseNotification->markAsShown(user);
        }
    }
}
```

So here's what i'm interested in:

1. Am i correct to assume that in second example the notification class is now OK with single responsibility principle?
2. All of the things that were happening in show() method are gone, but ... they are simply relocated to a method in a controller, so shouldn't it mean that this controller method now breaks single responsibility? If so, how can this be done to comply?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single responsibility principle (SRP) is often stated in the form of a quote by Robert C. Martin:

> A class should have only one reason to change.

In this case, the purpose of your `FirstUseNotification` class is to show a notification to a first-time user. So the only reason this class should need to change is if this purpose changes; and that is one reason, so the SRP is satisfied.

Note that this definition applies to a class, not to a method. That said, splitting this method into three methods probably *violates* the SRP, because if a user of this class needs to call three methods instead of one, then that user class has the responsibility of checking whether to show the notification, and marking the user as shown, *in addition to* the user class's own responsibility. `FirstUseNotification`'s responsibility is to "show a notification to a first-time user", not to provide an API that allows other classes to do that when it is not their responsibility.

In practice the `FirstUserNotification` class might have other reasons to change, if the details of how it shows the notification or accesses the database change. This can ideally be prevented by having stable interfaces for the notification and database classes, so that changes to those classes don't require changes to `FirstUseNotification` or other classes which show notifications and/or access the database. In practice this is not always 100% achieved, in which case the `FirstUseNotification` class might have some responsibilities to do with the details of showing a notification or accessing the database. But in theory, if those other classes handle their own responsibilities properly, then this class has only one reason to change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, as an unrelated question, in the first example, is there some other principle than SRP violated? I can't imagine having one method with a side effect (in this case writing to db) being a good thing.

Comment: The principle there is **"avoid side-effects"**. It's a principle of functional programming, but has benefits in other paradigms like OOP (and most popular languages, including Java, are multi-paradigm these days). The benefits include making the code easier to reason about, and easier to test in isolation from other code. To do unit tests of `FirstUserNotification` the way it's currently designed, you would probably have to mock out the notification-showing and database-updating parts; on the other hand, you could redesign it to return an object *representing* the state changes to be ...

Comment: ... made, which could be easier to test, because instead of mocking out the collaborators, you can test that it returns objects *representing the correct* notification and state change. On the other hand, that might make it harder to use, since you have to return a complex object representing multiple side-effects that need to be performed, and you have to have another class whose responsibility is to perform them. Generally for OOP, I suggest avoid side-effects where it's convenient, but you don't always need to.

Comment: You might also be interested in the [functional core, imperative shell](https://www.destroyallsoftware.com/screencasts/catalog/functional-core-imperative-shell) design pattern, which is related to this.